# Question about Extension Lemma for Smooth Functions: Lee, Smooth Manifolds, Lemma 2.26

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I may be overlooking something very simple, but I am reading the proof of Lemma 2.26 in Lee's Smooth Manifolds 2nd ed., and am a bit confused by the following statement:

For each $p\in A$, choose a neighborhood $W_p$ of $p$ and a smooth function $\tilde f_p:W_p\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ that agrees with $f$ on $W_p\cap A$.

How do we know such a neighborhood/function exists? I'm not sure how you would construct such a function, since you don't have a definition for $f$ away from $A$. Any insight here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have Lee's book, but I can tell you what I've seen this mean in other cases. We say that $f$ is of class $C^k$ on $A$ if for each $p \in A$ there exists a neighborhood $W_p$ of $p$ and a $C^k$ function $\tilde{f}_p$ on $W_p$ whose restriction to $A$ is $f$, i.e., $\left. \tilde{f}_p \right|_A = f$.

Comment: It might be helpful for those who don't have the book with them to state Lemma 2.26 and state what $A$ is.

Answer (score 5):

It's always a good idea to read the definitions. In the paragraph immediately before that lemma, I wrote:

> Suppose $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds with or without boundary, and $A\subseteq M$ is an arbitrary subset. We say that a map $F\colon A\to N$ is **smooth on $\boldsymbol A$** if it has a smooth extension in a neighborhood of
>   each point: that is, if for every $p\in A$ there is an open subset $W \subset M$ containing $p$ and a smooth map $F\colon W\to N$ whose restriction to $W \smallsetminus  A$ agrees with $F$.

(As a postscript, I should note that the definition above works fine in the situation considered in Lemma 2.26. However, I later realized because of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798923/whitney-extension-lemma-for-smooth-maps) that my definition needed to be modified in the case that the target manifold $N$ has nonempty boundary. A corrected definition in that case is given in my [list of corrections](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).)

Comment: Why does the definition need to be modified in the boundary case, @Jack Lee? I tried thinking through it but didn't succeed

Comment: @MartinGeller: My answer to the question I linked to above gave an example of a map into a manifold with boundary that should be smooth, but wouldn't be smooth by the definition I originally gave.